# Standard Documents or Software to write Test Scenarios (or functional tests)

Tags: standards, testing, scenarios

Are there standard documents around to write Test Scenarios (or functional tests/ acceptance tests)? Maybe software to input the scenarios and check them if passed...

Now we use Word or Excel to do this but having a system to track the results of previous test scenarios would be usefull.

thx, Lieven Cardoen

ps: The tests are pure functional tests. I mean the scenarios we describe should later be executed by persons who do not know the code or even the project. So the tests can not be executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard way to write test scenarios is probably in Use Case or User Story form. Google should give you plenty of links to choose from if you want to know more about these.

I'll just provide some more leads for you to investigate - your question is kind of broad.

For Java and .net there is [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/) It allows you to write test scenarios in a sort of wiki, and the tests can be executed.

You could look into [behavior driven development](http://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd), which has caused development of some frameworks to write executable user stories. For example [rspec](http://rspec.info/) for Ruby seems to be very popular. [Here](http://behaviour-driven.org/Implementations) is a list of such frameworks for many other platforms.